# Парсинг сайта с авторизацией. Parser

Tags: python, парсер, авторизация, request

**Мужики выручайте.**

Пробовал **парсить** разными программами и способами, но так и не удается авторизоваться на сайте https://nlstar.com/ru/office4/login/

прилагаю код

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as s:

AUTH_URL = 'https://nlstar.com/ru/office4/login/'
headers = {
    'Login': '007-2400101',
    'Password': '377609',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11.6; rv:51.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0.1',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Referer': 'https://nlstar.com/',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      }
    # Отправляем данные в POST, в session записываются наши куки

r=s.post(AUTH_URL, headers)
r=s.get('https://nlstar.com/')
print(r.text)
#403 ошибка
```

логин и пароль (тестовый) прилагается.

хотя бы намекните на авторизацию (передается логин, пароль и csrfmiddlewaretoken)

Comment: Попробуйте Selenium

Comment: `from grab import Grab`
`g = Grab()`
`g.setup(post={'login': '007-2400101', 'password': '377609'})`
`g.go('https://nlstar.com/ru/office4/login/')`
`g.go('https://nlstar.com/ru/office4/business/')`
`s= g.xpath_text('//title')`
 `print (s)`
   
    пробовал так, но увы(

Comment: c Selenium в браузере заскакивает на ура. Делая следующие пункты:    1.Trying to execute open on /ru/office4/login/
2.Trying to execute type on id=login with value 007-2400101
3.Trying to execute type on name=password with value 377609
4.Trying to execute clickAt on id=btn-login with value 37,34                              А как реализовать это на питоне/джава(приоритетней). При попытке изменить, все печальней=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests

url = 'https://nlstar.com/ru/office4/login/'

s = requests.Session()

r = s.get(url)
csrf_token = r.cookies['csrftoken']

data = {
    'login':        '007-2400101',
    'password':         '377609',
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token

}

d = s.post(url, data=data, headers=dict(Referer=url))
dd = s.get('https://nlstar.com/')
print(dd.text)
```

Comment: Дмитрий спасибо огромное, я все думал как токен запихнуть. От меня огромное человеческое спасибо.