# Как начать работу с парсингом сайта с авторизацией?

Tags: c#, парсер

Мне нужно распарсить сайт,на котором нужна авторизация, зайти на него без ввода логина и пароля можно перейдя по подобной ссылке https://mysite.ru/?token=f22f6adsadssda4234q44sa4a4a44aa4
,потом в браузере уже будет доступен переход по ссылке https://mysite.ru/vottyda/mnesyda   , работаю с anglesharp

Как правильно запихнуть токен для работы с дальнейшими страницами на сайте для парсинга или забить на токен?

P.S. нашел подобную тему, но увы с Phyton ([Парсинг сайта с авторизацией. Parser](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/825279/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-parser))

Comment: Вам стоит понять, как именно работает эта авторизация, отловите запросы, которые браузер отправляет при заходе и повторите их. Могу предположить, что при заходе по первой ссылке, сайт вешаем вам Cookie с неким именем, внутри которой находиться ваш токен. Вот вам надо эту куку отправлять при каждом запросе (при получение HTML).

Comment: Вы понимаете, что на сайте, который хотите распарсить может быть реализован свой метод авторизации, отличный от других? Стандартные методы авторизации - это OAuth и подобные, все остальное нужно смотреть и разбираться.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как можно взаимодействовать с сайтом через консольное приложение?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/606754/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)